# Validation for Search box

Tags: javascript, html

Need a validation for my search box that should allow space and %. The below mentioned letters should not be allowed.

```
< > ( ) ' " / \  * ; : = { } `(backtick) % + ^ ! - \x00-\x20
```

I tried by using JS code, please see the code :-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
    specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
    specialKeys.push(36); //Home
    specialKeys.push(35); //End
    specialKeys.push(37); //Left
    specialKeys.push(39); //Right
    function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

let me know what needs to be modified or added in the above mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Java Script Regular Expression to validate input following code will do what you want

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b _ _%]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is a working js fiddle example

[Validation Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uUWZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

**script**

```
$(function(){
    $("input.rejectSpecial").on('input', function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/(\>|\<|\(|\)|\"|\'|\\|\/|\*|;|\:|\=|\{|\}|`|%|\+|\^|\!|\-)/g, '');
    });
})
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="special letters not allowed" size="30" class="rejectSpecial"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="does nothing" size="30"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="special letters not allowed" size="30" class="rejectSpecial"/>
```